# Data freshness not working for Postgres data source in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am using PostgreSQL data source and have set data freshness to 12 hours. I would expect that when the data is loaded, I would be seeing the same and fast results till 12 hours because of caching. However, everytime I reload the page, I notice that the data changes (because more entries are being added to the DB) and I am not getting cached results.

How do I make caching work for postgres data sources?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other data sources in the report? If you do, the report will refresh all data sources at the shortest interval.

Comment: I have multiple charts on a page and each chart has a different PostgreSQL data source.